# Do I have to face security problems if I changing default role to Contributor

Tags: wp-admin, security

I am building a community site like medium.com.

Instead of creating front-end form, I am going to change default role as Contributor or allow subscriber role to insert posts/ CPT....

I need to know that, do I have to face security problems?

Answer (score 0):

No, that generally should be fine. Should, because the more access a user has, the more bugs he generally can trigger (or exploit), but from a conceptual point of view, it should be fine.

I personally wouldn't feel too secure with random people having access to my WP backend, but that might just be an unconscious bias.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between a Subscriber and a Contributor?

[image]

A Subscriber only has the `read` capability, while a Contributor also has the `edit_posts` and `delete_posts` capabilities. This means that a Contributor can edit and delete *their own* posts (but not others posts). You should be aware that it is also possible for plugins and themes to assign additional capabilities to a role; these are just the ones that the Contributor role has by default.

So will allowing anyone to become a contributor cause security issues?

No, it will not immediately make your site vulnerable. It will only allow users to create posts and delete them, and WordPress will not allow them to post unsafe content (preventing XSS).

However, it does increase the attack surface available to a would-be attacker. *If* there are any vulnerabilities in the post-related features, anybody will now be able to exploit them.

Based on my own experience researching security bugs in WordPress plugins, I can say that there are often vulnerabilities that aren't exploitable by Subscriber-level users but are exploitable by higher-level users. Sometimes a user must be an Author, Editor, or even Administrator though–just being a Contributor may not be sufficient.

That said, there are enough vulnerabilities that can be exploited *without having to even be a Subscriber* that I'd say the point is moot. Most attackers aren't going to bother creating an account so that they can perform an exploit. The best way to avoid getting hacked is to stay on top of the security of the plugins and theme that you use.

In addition, **allowing users to create new posts on the front end while only having the Subscriber role doesn't actually provide much protection**. You are basically turning a Subscriber into a Contributor then. Where they submit the post from is not important in regard to most of the exploits that would be relevant here.

So in the end, keeping the users as Subscribers is probably just giving you a false sense of security. As long as you don't install plugins that give Contributor-level users superpowers, you should be no worse off making "Contributor" the default role.